# Change in MySQL SQL syntax when use a derived table with parentheses

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0, derived-table

In my database, I have 2 table like this:

```
   b (b1 INT)
   c (c1 INT)
```

In MySQL version 5.7, I can run this query without error

```
   SELECT * FROM b JOIN ((SELECT * FROM c) tmp) ON b.b1 = tmp.c1
```

But in MySQL version 8.0, I got this error

```
   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ON b.b1 = TMP.c1 LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 1
```

When I remove the parentheses like this, it run successful

```
   SELECT * FROM b JOIN (SELECT * FROM c) tmp ON b.b1 = tmp.c1
```

I read on this link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-sql-changes but I can find any SQL change relate to my problem. So I don't know it's a bug or a change in MySQL syntax. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Can search/report mysql bugs on [bugs.mysql.com](https://bugs.mysql.com).  I [coudn't find any](https://bugs.mysql.com/search.php?search_for=+subquery&bug_type%5B%5D=Server%3A+Parser&status%5B%5D=Active&severity=&limit=30&order_by=&cmd=display&phpver=8.0&os=0&os_details=&bug_age=0&cpu_arch=0&cpu_arch_details=&last_updated=0&tags=&similar=). (or use [mariadb](https://dbfiddle.uk/aWokp0_N) that still support it, disclaimer, work for MariaDB Foundation).

Comment: In this case the parenthesis may act as "scalarization operator" (like in `WHERE column = (subquery)`). Anycase the situation when "code beautifying" produces incorrect SQL is common. And I shouldn't assume this to be a bug. You put the parenthesis, thay must act as... what they must do?